# How can I suppress ActiveX "ListBox_Click" event triggered by "Cells.Clear" method?

Tags: vba, excel

I  have a List Box with list style as radio button and Row source set to a dynamic data range.

```
With SearchActionwordForm.SearchResultListBox
.ColumnCount = LastColumn - 1
.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
.RowSource = DataRange
.Selected(0) = True
End With
```

ListBox value is populated based on some text entered by a user. Each time a user enters new search text the data range will be changed. I have code to clear the whole sheet before writing new data to the sheet.

```
Set ExcelAppl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
ws.Cells.Clear
Dim rng As Range
'code to fetch data from Recordset
Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
lFieldCount = rs.Fields.Count

'copy record values starting from second row of the worksheet:
rng.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs

'Get the Last Column Number
Dim rLastCell As Range
Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
LastColumn = rLastCell.Column
LastColAdd = rLastCell.Address
LastCellCol = ExtractLetter(LastColAdd)
Set rLastCell = Nothing

'Get the Last Cell Address
Set rLastCell = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
LastColumnAddress = rLastCell.Address
LastCellRow = ExtractNumber(LastColumnAddress)
LastColumnAddress = LastCellCol & LastCellRow
DataRange = "B2:" & LastColumnAddress

'Write headers to excel
For i = 0 To LastColumn - 1
 rng.Offset(0, i).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next i

wb.Save
```

The "Ws.cells.clear" method triggers the "ListBox_Click" event that is supposed to be triggered when I click on the listbox.

Is it possible to suppress this event for this particular scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible to suppress this event for this particular scenario?

Yes: define a global Boolean variable which is always true ***except*** when you perform the `ws.cells.clear` -- you set the Boolean to false right before this, and back to true afterwards.  Your routine that handles `ListBox_Click` would check if this Boolean is false, and if so, it performs no action; otherwise it does its normal thing.

You can disable the `ListBox_Click` handling using this variable if any other scenarios come up where you don't want the code to run as well.  Just be sure to restore the Boolean to True when the interval when you don't want the processing to occur is over.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better avoid .Rowsource to populate any listbox/combobox.
Use .list instead : 
e.g

```
 listbox1.list=range("A1:K12").Value
```

Comment: Of course! this solution could also help me to get rid of the above problem, But I will loose the "column headers" in list box that I am getting very easily using "Row Source". Thanks for the solution.